# "PSI" bus on HP 3000

Tags: hp

I came across a mention of a "PSI bus" in reference to late-model HP 3000 machines. I thought this was simply a typo for "PCI bus", but a google search suggests this really was a thing.

Looking over what little documentation I can find that mentions it, I can't even tell what it was. Is this a physical specification? I see that it hangs off the HPPB/NIO bus internally, so it would seem the interface side *is* HPPB.

For those who know of this, was it used on any other system? It appears to be appear only on HP-PA systems, not the "classic" line?

Comment: PSI might also stand for "programmable serial interface" e.g. something more custom than the standard serial protocols.

Comment: Seems to a bus off the HP Precision Bus. ref: "System organization" and also diagrams under sections "Workstation and serial connections" and "Buses" from http://www.3kranger.com/HP3000/mpeix/doc3k/B59608250.11943/14.htm

Comment: I think @Brian hit it - it appears this is not a bus so much as a smart serial card with protocol support for Bisync and similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where you read about a PSI ***bus*** <sup>(1)</sup> but the PSI was actually a programmable serial interface *card* that could plug into the HP-PB Precision Bus and allow communication with a wide variety of serial devices, using protocols such as SDLC and X.25.

Documentation for it can be found [here](https://documen.site/download/hp-precision-bus-hp-pb-hewlett-packard-enterprise-community_pdf) and, if you read through that, it's really more of a physical interface (on both the HP and comms equipment side) that can be configured to talk to many different devices.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> The link given in this answer does talk about the "Hewlett-Packard Precision Bus Programmable Serial Interface (HP-PB PSI) card" so it may have been something like that where the "bus" was mistakenly associated with the PSI card rather than the Precision Bus.